# Is there a probability scenario that can fit this series?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I thought of this nice series the other day, which has a rather neat closed form.

$$\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4} + ... +\frac{1}{1+2+3+...+n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$$

And I was thinking, surely this series looks like it can be used to evaluate some sort of probability.

Rather than the usual question of "Here's a scenario, can you help me find the probability?", I am now asking a slight twist on that, being

> What kind of scenario would have the above series to evaluate its probability?

So for example, some sort of 'pulling balls from urns' kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work, but a variation on it might.

An evil supervillain has infected me with a horrible disease, which will kill me after the end of $n$ days. The cure to my disease is in a red-coloured vial in a box, but there is also a blue-coloured vial which contains water. At the beginning of day $i$ of my $n$ days (where we start just before the beginning of day 1), the supervillain adds $i+1$ blue water vials to the urn, and replaces the one from which I drank yesterday. I may take one vial per day. What is the probability that I survive the horrible disease?

Comment: Is your result just my series above, but the fractions are multiplied instead of added?

Comment: My result is missing several multiplication terms. It's actually $\frac{1}{1+2} + (1-\frac{1}{1+2})(\frac{1}{1+2+3} + \dots )$

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your result? I cannot see what goes on beyond the "..."